# Update, if not exists Insert using XML input parameter in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TelecommunicationsNumber]
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ContactTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CountryID] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

Here is my sample XML input to the above mentioned table.

```
DECLARE @TelecommunicationsNumberList XML = '<TelecommunicationsNumber><ContactTypeID>2</ContactTypeID><CountryID>1</CountryID></TelecommunicationsNumber><TelecommunicationsNumber><ContactTypeID>4</ContactTypeID><CountryID>1</CountryID></TelecommunicationsNumber>'
```

I figured out the UPDATE SQL query as below.

```
UPDATE TelecommunicationsNumber
SET ContactTypeID = n.ContactTypeID,
    CountryID = n.CountryID
FROM (SELECT
          T.C.value('(ContactTypeID)[1]', 'INT') AS ContactTypeID,
          T.C.value('(CountryID)[1]', 'INT') AS CountryID
      FROM 
          @TelecommunicationsNumberList.nodes('/TelecommunicationsNumber') AS T (C)) AS n
WHERE 
    TelecommunicationsNumber.ContactTypeID = n.ContactTypeID
```

How can I insert a new record if the input XML and the `TelecommunicationsNumber` table does exists the same `ContactTypeID` and update if exists.

In order to do that first I have to fetch the rows in order to check weather the same `ContactTypeID` exists or not.

**QUESTION**: I am unable to figure out the SELECT query. How can I integrate both the insert and update queries by writing the SELECT query.

I use the below query to INSERT the records.

```
  INSERT INTO TelecommunicationsNumber (ContactTypeID,CountryID)
      SELECT
          Entries.value('(ContactTypeID)[1]', 'INT') AS 'ContactTypeID',
          Entries.value('(CountryID)[1]', 'nvarchar(256)') AS 'CountryID'
      FROM 
          @TelecommunicationsNumberList.nodes('/TelecommunicationsNumber') AS TelecommunicationsNumberEntries (Entries)
```

Comment: Have a look at [`merge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) which allows you to specify an `update` when a row exists, and an `insert` when it does not

Comment: @Andomar Thanks for the comment. I was able to resolve my problem using the `merge` command. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue using `MERGE` command.

```
;
  WITH TelecommunicationsNumber
  AS (SELECT
    ParamValues.x1.value('ContactTypeID[1]', 'int') AS ContactTypeID,
    ParamValues.x1.value('CountryID[1]', 'int') AS CountryID
  FROM @TelecommunicationsNumberList.nodes('/TelecommunicationsNumber') AS ParamValues (x1))
  MERGE INTO dbo.TelecommunicationsNumber AS old
  USING TelecommunicationsNumber AS new
  ON (new.ContactTypeID = old.ContactTypeID)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  old.CountryID = new.CountryID
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (ContactTypeID, CountryID)
  VALUES (new.ContactTypeID, new.CountryID);
```